# C: Allocating memory confusion

Tags: c, memory-management

For this code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int *f (int n)
{
    int *ptr = malloc (sizeof (int));
    *ptr = n;
    return ptr;
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    int **ptr = malloc (sizeof (int *));
    ptr[0] = f (0);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        ptr = realloc (sizeof (int *) * (i + 2));
        ptr[i + 1] = malloc (sizeof (int));
        ptr[i + 1] = f (i + 1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", *ptr[i]);
        free (ptr[i]);
    }
    free (ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

does program allocate twice than it is needed?

Comment: Yes, and it leaks memory, too.

Comment: I guess here things are academic (homework), but `valgrind --leak-check=full` can help nicely here (compile your program with debug info to get line numbers where you might be leaking memory). Note, btw, that your current version of the program won't compile.

Comment: What do _you_ think? And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, You don't need the malloc in main as it is immediately overwritten on the next line and you leak that memory. Is this a homework question?

**EDIT for question change**

This is now leaking memory in an odd way.

The first few lines aren't leaking but when you get into the loop you're allocating and assigning randomly. (As a first, realloc takes as it's first arguement a pointer to reallocate, so you're missing `ptr` in there)

Now you're allocating `ptr` to be of size 2, then 3 then 4 etc... up to 6. And then immediately leaking that memory as you overwrite the pointer with the call to `f()`

You could write that all like this:

```
int i;
int **ptr = malloc (sizeof(int*) * 6);
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    ptr[i] = f(i);
}
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    printf ("%d\n", *ptr[i]);
    free (ptr[i]);
}
free (ptr);
return 0;
```

As an aside, you should in general try not to allocate memory too often, it is *relatively* slow. If you can use the stack you should, and if not, try and allocate all the memory you need up front, calling realloc in a loop is a bad idea and should be avoided.

In this specific case you don't need a pointer to a pointer, you could have just allocated one array of 6 integers, with `int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 6)` and then `array[0] = 0;` which would be easier and better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does allocate twice the needed memory. Also, the value of "ptr" in main is overwrite by return of "f" so you don't even have a chance to free it. You could remove the call to malloc in "main":

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr = f (3);
    printf ("%d\n", *ptr);
    free (ptr);
    return 0;
}
```